# Method for Creating Structurally Different Trees in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

My question is very similar to this: [Structural Different trees java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802517/structural-different-trees-java). Included there is the code.

I think the question asker for that question is doing the same paper as me as our code is exactly the same to the spelling errors in the BinaryTreeNode class :)

I don't understand how to actually go about creating the different Trees though. Maybe I've just missed something or I'm caught in a rut but I cannot seem to figure out how to go about creating the different trees to begin with. Counting them i think I would be fine with, again just because of the Catalan numbers situation, but how do you go left - right - left or whatever you need to do? :(

This is an assignment, and I have been trying really hard to get my head around this by myself, but I just can't seem to make any progress with this particular question. I'm not asking for a complete answer or an easy way to do it, I really just don't get what I'm supposed to be doing..

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You want to build an algorithm starting from the root and building cases iteratively.
0 nodes: 1 arrangement with 0 nodes: null
1 node: 1 arrangement with 1 node: root
2 nodes: 2 arrangements with 2 nodes: root: left and root: right
3 nodes: 4 arrangements with 3 nodes: root: left: left, root left: right, root: left, right, root: right: left, root: right: right
etc.
So, meth(2, 2) should return:
0 nodes: 1 arrangement with 0 nodes
1 node: 1 arrangement with 1 node
2 nodes: 2 arrangements with 2 node
(treeNode -- (TreeNode))
or something similar